# Gridview paging in c#, dynamic SQL query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, gridview

I am new to c#, using Visual Studio 2010.

I created a grid view and enabled paging. It works fine with all the data.

But I have few drop downs and filter buttons at the top of the page. When I press each filter buttons the grid view show filtered data only.

I wrote each SQL statement for the button click events.

Suppose that I have 60 records and grid view shows 10 record per page. When I click filter button and suppose it shows only 25 records. That means there is only 3 pages showing. That is ok and works. But when I click second or third page it will again show all the data, that means 5 pages.

I know the problem is it run the default SQL query (that I use to bind data to grid view in graphical mood). But I need to know how to fix it. I only need to do is show each page without changing the filtered data.

Here is my grid view code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="DocumentID"
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None"
    onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged"
    style="font-family: Tahoma; font-size: small; text-align: center;"
    Width="100%" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True"
    onpageindexchanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
    <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="DocumentID" HeaderText="Document ID"
    InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="DocumentID" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="DocumentType" HeaderText="Document Type"
    SortExpression="DocumentType" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="ReceivedDate" HeaderText="Received Date"
    SortExpression="ReceivedDate" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Title" />
    <asp:CommandField SelectText="&gt;&gt;"
    ShowSelectButton="True" />
    </Columns>
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerSettings PageButtonCount="5" Mode="NumericFirstLast" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
    <PagerSettings Mode="NumericFirstLast" PageButtonCount="10"  FirstPageText="First" LastPageText="Last"/>
</asp:GridView>
```

and my `pageindexchanging` is

```
    protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        //GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

and here is my `SqlDataSource`

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT InwardDetails.DocumentID, InwardDetails.Title, DocumentTypeDetails.DocumentType, InwardDetails.ReceivedDate FROM InwardDetails INNER JOIN DocumentTypeDetails ON InwardDetails.DocumentType = DocumentTypeDetails.DocumentTypeID"> 
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Why commenting Gridview binding in Paging menthod?

Answer (score 1):

Bind the grid from code behind. And when you use any filter, use **rowfilter** to filter the data and **bind the grid again** to give updated data. Use databind everytime a filter is applied or removed inorder to get the new data.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlConnection myCon = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd, myCon);
    adapter.Fill(ds);
    DataView view = new DataView();
    view.Table = ds.Tables[0];
    view.RowFilter = "ColumnName = " + TextBox1.Text.Trim();
    GridView1.DataSource = view;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```